# Help with partitioning in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I'm a total noob at Linux. In fact, the only version of Linux I ever used was 12.04 through WUBI. I know just a little but recently I deleted Windows 7 off my hard drive and I just did a flash drive installation of 12.04.

Well it's been a while and when I had Windows 7, my hobby was making YouTube videos/editing photos and such. Well to get back on track with that I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 12.04. No problem but I really miss having Windows so I made a bootable USB drive of Windows 8 and I went to install it but it says my hard drive isn't formatted in NTFS and it wouldn't let me format it in the installer.

I'm not planning on leaving Ubuntu Studio 12.04 any time soon but there are just some programs that I can't run in Linux nor is there software like them. So to wipe/format my hard drive to NTFS, people are saying I have to use a Live CD/USB and do it from there.

I don't have any space USB drives or discs. So, I'm left with partitioning and for some reason GParted won't let me do it. Below is a photo (i.imgur.com).

Sorry I couldn't post the image as I'm a new member.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry buddy I'm here to help. It's a lengthy process but there's no other way since a program called unetbootin does not work any more.

1. Firstly go to GParted (if you have it installed) then choose your USB drive from the drop down and format it as NTFS, make sure you can boot from it, to do this on GParted click on your USB drive and right-click and click manage flags make sure your that "**boot**" is ticked.
2. Then go to the Ubuntu Software Center and type into the search field "**Wine**".
3. When it's installed download **7zip**, (make sure you download the `.exe` version which is the Windows version)
4. After that right-click on the `.exe` and go to Properties and go to the "Permissions tab" and tick allow executing the program (it'll say something like that)
5. After that locate your Windows 8 iso. through 7 zip by clicking on one of the drives, it won't be the C:/ drive.
6. After you've found the iso, create a file on your desktop called Windows 8 .iso and then extract each file in the iso one by one on to your into that file which you've made, make that file on the desktop to make it easier to find.
7. After you've extracted each file to the windows 8 folder and everything in the iso drag the files (not the windows 8 iso- just the files inside) to your USB, one by one.
8. When that's done restart and boot from your USB like you would when you installed Linux off a USB.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing Gparted or try using a different partitioning tool by type in partition in the ubuntu software centre.